# Share my local wordpress site with another developer with git

Tags: wordpress, git

I want to share my local wordpress site with another developer with git in a way our database will be same when he setups my wordpress site in his local PC.

I am using windows 7 OS

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you are asking for is possible.

here is my suggestion (the database should be on a real server)

if you use CPanel:
1- In the CPanel create the database and new user and assign the user to the database  
2- In the CPanel Go to Remote MySQL, add your IP address and the other developer IP address. (to allow remote access)
3- Export the database from your local PC and import it to the CPanel. 
4- Change the wp-config.php configuration. 
**Note:** The urls should be the same on your PC and the developer pc. 
for example if your website url on your pc is : http://localhost/mywebsite/
the other developer should make it the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping your database out of git (except perhaps the database definitions).

Instead you can leverage git hooks. Using something like `pre-push`, run a mysql dump command to get the current state of your db, and copy it to a shared Dropbox/Drive folder with your team mate.

```
.git/hooks/pre-push
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > ~/Dropbox/shared-with-tm/mysql.sql
```

**Completely untested** This is a vague answer to answer a vague question - but might give you a starting point.

Comment: Could do in pre-commit something like mysqldump, and then add the file to commit. And track the file in git LFS.